# Error using ghost4j ln Linux Machine

Tags: java, ghostscript

I use [ghost4j GhostScript](http://www.ghost4j.org/) to convert PDF to TIF files in a Java Standalone Application.

I included Ghost4J into my project using Maven and installed Ghostscript (Windows) into C:\Program Files\gs... I tested the code in Window's everything worked fine. Life's good.

When I test the same application in Linux, it's not working expected. Gave me the below error.

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4" Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-24" Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary
    at org.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:323)
```

I went through the code again, I am adding the GS libraries to the library path and the able to create the GhostScript instance

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.19\\bin");
     Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();
     synchronized (gs) {
                gs.initialize(gsArgs);
                gs.exit();
            }
```

When running the Linux machine, I am passing `gs-919-linux_x86_64` this executable.

Did anyone faced this issue when running Ghostscript in Linux machine ? B.T.W I did not install GhostScript in Linux.

Comment: Why did you use the "itext" and "pdfbox" labels?

Comment: Tags deleted. The only remote connection with iText is that it uses Ghostscript in its tests, but that is native Ghostscript, not the ghost4j wrapper, because it also has to work in iText for .NET.

Comment: Also, installing a wrapper for Ghostscript, but not installing Ghostscript itself, I am not sure how that is ever going to work.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse You can execute the GhostScript command using the ProcessBuilder or Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(GSCOMMAND). By any chance did you work on GhostScript for a Java application ?

Comment: I already answered that question in my first comment.

Comment: See also [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)